# unpack a nested dataclass and named tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a function that unpacks nested `dataclass`es and `namedtuple`s (or a combination of both)

---

**my attempt**

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39235373/9253013) answer about how to unpack a named tuple, and i am simply extending it:

the unpack function

```
def unpack(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {key: unpack(value) for key, value in obj.items()}
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        return [unpack(value) for value in obj]
    elif is_named_tuple_instance(obj):
        return {key: unpack(value) for key, value in obj._asdict().items()}
    elif is_data_class_instance(obj):
        return {key: unpack(getattr(obj, key)) for key in obj.__dataclass_fields__.keys()}
    elif isinstance(obj, tuple):
        return tuple(unpack(value) for value in obj)
    else:
        return obj
```

the `is_data_class_instance` function:

```
def is_data_class_instance(obj):
    data_class_attrs = {'__dataclass_fields__', '__dataclass_params__'}
    return set(dir(obj)).intersection(data_class_attrs) == data_class_attrs
```

---

side note, would this be acceptable type hints ?

```
from typing import NamedTuple, Any, NewType, Union

DataClass = NewType('DataClass', Any)
def unpack(obj: Union[DataClass, NamedTuple, Any]) -> Union[tuple, list, dict, Any]:
    ...
```

Comment: This is interesting, if you solved it a solution would be appreciated. I wonder why you didn't use dataclasses.astuple, that seems a simple way to unpack, although I am not sure about recursively as your function.

Comment: @Davos what do you mean by "solve"? The code runs as expected

Comment: Oh I see now this site is Code Review, I thought this was a question, my mistake. Regarding the type hints, I think if you are going to put `Any` in a `Union` type then it makes other types in the `Union` redundant.